# Java sl4j-log4j logging libraries not working properly

Tags: java, log4j, logback, slf4j

[image]
.

I'm trying to compile a java program using these jars(screenshot) but getting these errors:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/vanar/workspace/TwitterKafka/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/vanar/workspace/TwitterKafka/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]

Exception in thread "hosebird-client-io-thread-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
       at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:120)
       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.shutdown(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:276)
       at com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.ClientBase.run(ClientBase.java:165)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**how do I ensure all these logging components work together?
I am stumped as to what is compatible with what and do not know a way apart from trial and error which I tried with no luck. please help**

Comment: Are you sure you have only slf4j.jar in your class path? and is it the latest version?

Comment: Please post all of the libraries you are using. I think you might be using a lib  which itself includes log4j with sfl4j. e.g storm-kafka

Comment: I'm using kafka-client jar in this. does this impact in any way?

Comment: if someone could suggest the pom.xml for me including the exclusions from the dependencies then this could work  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add logging jar files to endorsed directory.

Comment: I don't understand the "endorsed directory" in this case. Please elaborate

Comment: JRE endorsed directory under Linux  is <java-home>/lib/endorsed. If you use Tomcat then "$CATALINA_HOME/endorsed" can be used. The goal is to make logging jar files avaliable through bootstrap or system class loader.

Comment: one more thing. if you do so then this jar files must be excluded from application class path. Provided scope can be used in case of Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Use latest combination of slf4j-log4j .You are using older version of any one of this jars.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

add log4j and sl4j jar in this combination. if any one is missing exception raised while logging.